# Node.js Deployment in openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift

I was trying to deploy a Node.js application to the openshift as in this link [here](http://myapp-jeewan.rhcloud.com/)

I understand this code

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('Hello Http');
});
server.listen(3000);
```

and there is no issue running it locally

```
$ node server.js // saved as server.js
```

However, how does this work when I commit this application in openshift? This is very simple code. I have some downloaded code that is a chat application and client-server need to configure to listen on some port (I was using port number 3000 in my localhost).

It works on port number 3000 in localhost but how can I make it to work in Openshift?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to listen on port `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT`. So something like this should work:

```
server.listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000);
```

See here for example: [Error: listen EACCES on Openshift app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171542/error-listen-eacces-on-openshift-app)

Comment: Hi Nitzan, I tried this code but does not seem to work. It now says "socket.io.js not found". I googled about it and tried some different codes but nothing seems work. Everything works fine locally but when I upload the same code in openshift, it does not work. Mainly, it does not find the socket.io.js file. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Your original problem is solved, you are now facing another problem. I suggest you accept this answer, and open a new question regarding that "socket.io.js not found". It's a different problem, and people in the future who might look for it won't search according to this question's title. It will also give other people a chance to answer. In that new question, you should definitely include directory structure and relevant logs. Describe the problem better: who is "it" (in "it now says...") -- the client? the server? something else?

Comment: Hi Nitzan, sorry for this. I was in a hurry this morning just to reply your answer and totally forgot to accept your answer. I am accepting your answer, thank you so much. I searched a lot and tried live in Openshift server to fix it but could not resolve it. I will do more research on it later today. Sorry about that, I am accepting your answer and thank you so much for this.

Comment: no problems at all. let me know when you create a new question, and post your directory structure and logs there.

Comment: Hi Nitzan, sure I will and yes I need some of your guidance as I am really interested in Node.js and learning from the bottom. Somehow, localhost:portNumber works for me but Openshift does not seem to work and I suspect that the version of Node.js may be different from Openshift to my local (I need to check).

Comment: This is my new deployment of the chat App in Node.js http://chat-jeewan.rhcloud.com/  . This is perfectly working in my localhost but throwing an error (see in the console) for socket.io and really not sure why its not finding socket when I deployed it in Openshift.

Comment: We should move this thread to a chat ourselves. Long comment threads are not "polite" on SO. Incidentally, it works for me (my browser *does* download socket.io.js from `cdn.socket.io/stable`).

Answer (score 2):

Hey the issue with socket.io is that you have that npm package installed local but not in openshift (dependencies don't get pushed). For that you can login thru ssh (look for "Want to log in to your application?" in right menu in openshift control panel, follow [instructions](https://www.openshift.com/developers/remote-access) and use the ssh connection provided) then login with terminal o Putty, and go to:

```
cd app-root/repo
```

or

```
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
```

and then

```
npm install socket.io
```

I've used that to install mongoose and other dependencies without trouble. Also you can use

```
node server.js
```

from command line to run the site ;)

Comment: Just `npm install` after checking out code from openshift and it will get required packages (that are defined in package.json) to you locally